# Route order in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

We are implementing routes programmatically using a implementation of `RouteDefinitionLocator`. We have two services which should register at the same route path, where one of them is meant as a fallback if the other one does not exist. The preferred route with the specific path is:

```
RouteDefinition{id='CompositeDiscoveryClient_ms-1400133464', predicates=[PredicateDefinition{name='Path', args={pattern=/yambas/rest/apps/*/models/ms/**}}], filters=[FilterDefinition{name='RewritePath', args={regexp=/yambas/rest/apps/(?<remaining>.*), replacement=/ms/apps/${remaining}}}], uri=lb://ms, order=0}
```

And the more general one, which should only fire if other route was found:

```
RouteDefinition{id='CompositeDiscoveryClient_yambas-1171178634', predicates=[PredicateDefinition{name='Path', args={pattern=/yambas/rest/**}}], filters=[], uri=lb://yambas, order=0}
```

Thus, when calling `/yambas/rest/apps/bla/models/ms`, the first route should be used, and when calling `/yambas/rest/apps/bla/models/otherms/*`, the second (fallback ) should be used.

Problem is, that even the *order* attribute at the route seems not to solve this; currently we find no possibility to set up this order / priority of routes. Is this intendet?

Comment: They are both order 0 which means it's random. Did you set an order and it isn't reflected? What version are you using?

Comment: Hi Spencer, i tried setting the first one to order 50 and the second to 0 - then it does not find any route for `/yambas/rest/apps/bla/models/ms`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that we set the order the wrong way - setting the lower priority route to order 1 and the higher to 0 makes it work.

@spencergibb that would be definitely worth to be mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 10):

The more specific routes should appear first in the routing configuration, generic ones at the end.

For example:  `http://gateway-url/v1/accounts/**` always matches with the `route-id-1` while `http://gateway-url/v1/**` matches with `route-id-2`

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: route-id-1
        uri: http://www.someurl.com
        order: 0
        predicates:
        - Path=/v1/accounts/** #<--
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/v1/accounts/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
      - id: route-id-2
        uri: http://www.someurl1.com
        order: 1
        predicates:
        - Path=/v1/** #<--
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/v1/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

Comment: Leave some references:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#retrieving-the-routes-defined-in-the-gateway. 

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/commit/20152a7477881ec7e23c8b0ba36cd0a96142c0b7.

Answer (score 0):

About the route order, it was answered at [Is there a recommended order range for Filters in Spring Cloud Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70654321/11836961).

TL;DR
The order is based on `org.springframework.core.Ordered` interface, which lower values have higher precedence, as also mentioned by @andreas.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34984180)