# Is there a recommended order range for Filters in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I would like to know if there is a recommended order range for Gateway Filters (global or not) in Spring Cloud Gateway because there are Spring Gateway filters with orders less than 1 and greater than 9999 in gateway chain. See:

```
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20770} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@5eb974}, order = -2147483648]"
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20771} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@ae5eeee}, order = -2147482648]"
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20772} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@492c1b1b}, order = -1]"
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20774} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@3927de0e}, order = 0]"
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20775} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@36dab184}, order = 0]"

// my custom filters should be here

{OrderedGatewayFilter@20791} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@72f112d1}, order = 10000]"
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20792} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@71b9b035}, order = 10150]"
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20793} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@4c475547}, order = 2147483646]"
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20794} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@189f5ed8}, order = 2147483647]"
{OrderedGatewayFilter@20795} "[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@10faebc9}, order = 2147483647]"
```

My custom global filters implements Ordered interface:

```java
@Component
public class GlobalFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) { ... }
 
    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 2; // here
    }
}
```

And my Gateway filters are OrderedGatewayFilter:

```java
@Component
public class CustomFilter implements GatewayFilterFactory<CustomFilter.Config> {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> {
           ...
        }, 3); // here
    }

   ...
}
```

Should my filters be inside 1..9999 range? Or is there no problem in put my custom filters before or after these Spring Cloud Gateway filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter chain is sorted by the org.springframework.core.Ordered interface. According to the Spring Framework documentation on [Annotation Type Order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html):

> The default value is Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE, indicating lowest
> priority (losing to any other specified order value).

But

> Lower values have higher priority.

If you check that in your IDE, the lowest possible value (Which has the highest precedence) is -2147483648. The highest possible value is 2147483647.

Judging from the documentation on [Global Filters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#global-filters) and a bit of experience, -1 is a starting point and you can arrange the order you need around that.
Or if you have one filter that always needs to be executed first, use Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE and order the other filters from there, like Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE+1 etc.

EDIT: Spring Cloud Gateway has some hardcoded Filter Orders inside, e.g. "WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER = -1" in the [NettyWriteResponseFilter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/main/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/NettyWriteResponseFilter.java). If you're worried about interference, check the [source code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway) for ordering.